# MinecraftServer.getServer returns null MinecraftForge

Tags: java, null, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to get the MinecraftServer instance in MinecraftForge.

Here's the code I've been trying:

```
MinecraftServer minecraftServer = MinecraftServer.getServer();
if(minecraftServer == null){
     System.out.println("null!!!")
}
```

When I ran the mod, here is the response:

```
[p.a.c.a:pr:92]: null!!!!
```

I have also tried to use FMLCommonHandler, and the code I used was:

```
MinecraftServer minecraftServer = FMLCommandHandler.instance().getMinecraftServerInstance();
if(minecraftServer == null){
     System.out.println("null!!!");
}
```

And, the same response as the current code.

```
[p.a.c.a:pr:92]: null!!!!
```

And finally, tried FMLServerHandler and the code I used was:

```
MinecraftServer minecraftServer = FMLServerHandler.instance().getServer();
if(minecraftServer == null){
    System.out.println("null!!!")
}
```

The response was also:

```
[p.a.c.a:pr:92]: null!!!!
```

Comment: Possibly migrate this to GameDev.SE? What's the border line for SO and GameDev questions?

Comment: You're doing probably the same thing wrong as http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/index.php?topic=18387.0

Comment: I have checked that all my code is server-side and not client side, and plus I have checked the forum post before and it did not resolve my problem.

Comment: @zapl The forum post said to send a packet to retrieve the server instance, how would one do that?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/mapping-and-modding-tutorials/2137055-1-7-x-1-8-customizing-packet-handling-with) link out

Comment: @Jonah I still don't understand how to get a server instance from a packet.

Comment: I'm gonna be trying to create a new FakePlayer and then get the server instance from the fake player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out! Made a FakePlayer and then got the minecraft server instance from the player without messing with packets.

Code I used:

```
WorldServer worldServer = DimensionManager.getWorld(0); // default world
GameProfile gameProfile = new GameProfile(UUID.randomUUID(), "FakePlayer");
FakePlayer fakePlayer = new FakePlayer(worldServer, gameProfile);
MinecraftServer minecraftServer = fakePlayer.mcServer;
```

Comment: how do you make a FakePlayer etc.? Could you show me some code?